# Unsupported SuppressWarnings CloneDoesntCallSuperClone, FieldCanBeLocal, ObjectAllocationInLoop, UnusedAssignment, WeakerAccess

Tags: java, eclipse, annotations, suppress-warnings

I imported a project into eclipse and get the following warnings:

- Unsupported @SuppressWarnings("CloneDoesntCallSuperClone")
- Unsupported @SuppressWarnings("FieldCanBeLocal")
- Unsupported @SuppressWarnings("ObjectAllocationInLoop")
- Unsupported @SuppressWarnings("UnusedAssignment")
- Unsupported @SuppressWarnings("UnusedParameters")
- Unsupported @SuppressWarnings("UnusedReturnValue")
- Unsupported @SuppressWarnings("WeakerAccess")

Examples of these annotations can be found [here](https://github.com/apache/mahout/blob/master/math/src/main/java/org/apache/mahout/math/SequentialAccessSparseVector.java) and [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/idea/+/d9e4c285fa2c3c38c5b92cf30e77f27e243566a8/java/java-analysis-impl/src/com/intellij/codeInspection/nullable/NullableStuffInspectionBase.java). I tried jdk 1.5-1.7 but no change. Sow how do I get rid of those?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These warnings are from [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html) and are not supported by Eclipse.

You can turn of the message in 'Preferences > Java > Compiler > Errors/Warnings', expand the 'Annotations' section and change 'Unhandled token in @SuppressWarnings' to Ignore.

Comment: This warning is useful in other circumstances. By disabling the feature all together, you will lose precious information. There is a bug report on Eclipse project: feel free to support this issue: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=392045